# Why do I always get "Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out." on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, https

Why do I always get:

> "Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out."

in Chrome on https but works well on http?

No problem with the network because other browsers like firefox didn't get anything wrong.

What happened? And how to solve it?

Platform: Kubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Comment: Can you share with us the URL that is failing in Chrome?  Are you saying that https://www.domain.com gives the above error in Chrome, but works correctly in Firefox?

Comment: All URL starting with https

Comment: Are you running any firewall software on your Kubuntu system?

Comment: No firewall or other software like that

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: Version 21.0.1180.89